# How do I create an array based off an existing array where each element of the new array copies the original array until the first tab character in C

Tags: arrays, c, char, substring, c-strings

I have an array of strings read from a file. I'd like to take each string in the existing array and copy it to a new array unit the first instance of a tab character, and then move to the next element in the array.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please _edit_ your _question_ and post your existing code in code block here. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard C function `strchr`. For example if you have two character arrays like

```
char s1[12] = "Hello\tWorld";
char s2[12];
```

then you can write

```
char *p = strchr( s1, '\t' );

if ( p != NULL )
{
    memcpy( s2, s1, p - s1 );
    s2[p - s1] = '\0';
}
else
{
    strcpy( s2, s1 );
}
```

For two dimensional arrays you can do the same in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function `until_tabs` that takes an array of strings and the array's length. Then we allocate a same sized array of char pointers and iterate over the original array.

For each string input we can use `strchr` to look for a tab. If it's absent, just duplicate the string with `strdup`. Otherwise allocate an adequately sized buffer for the new string and copy everything before `'\t'` into it with `strncpy`.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char **until_tabs(char **strings, size_t n) {
    char **result = malloc(sizeof(char *) * n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char *tab = strchr(strings[i], '\t');
        if (!tab) {
            result[i] = strdup(strings[i]);
            continue;
        }

        size_t size = tab-strings[i];
        result[i] = malloc(size+1);
        strncpy(result[i], strings[i], size);
        result[i][size] = '\0';
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    char *arr[] = {"hello", "world", "foo\tbar"};
    char **arr2 = until_tabs(arr, 3);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", arr2[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hello
world
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

For each string in the array of strings:

**Find the length of the string, but only up to a potential `'\t'`**

```
size_t length == strcspn(source_string, "\t");
```

**Allocated needed memory**

```
char *destination_string = malloc(length + 1); // +1 for the null character.
if (destination_string == NULL) Handle_Allocation_Error();
```

**Copy it**

```
memcpy(destination_string, source_string, length);
destination_string[length] = '\0';

// or 

sprintf(destination_string, ".*s", (int) length, source_string);

// or 
strncpy(destination_string, source_string, length);
destination_string[length] = '\0';
```